# Remove vertical spacing between normal text line and loop made with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I want to delete this vertical spacing that appears everytime I draw a loop using tikzcd-  This vertical spacing only appears when I draw a loop, so I don't want to modify the normal spacing of all the document, just the spacing of that line. Any idea?? Thank you

[image: La necesidad de que $Q$ no tenga ciclos dirigidos es para que los espacios vectoriales tengan dimensión finita en cada vértice. Por ejemplo, si $\mathbb{L} =$ \quad \begin{tikzcd}[cramped] 1 \arrow[out=0,in=90,loop, "\alpha"]\end{tikzcd}entonces $S(1) = \quad <{ \alpha ^n : \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0 }> \quad = \quad k^{\mathbb{N}}$]

```
 La necesidad de que $Q$ no tenga ciclos dirigidos es para que los    
 espacios vectoriales tengan dimensión finita en cada vértice. Por 
 ejemplo, si $\mathbb{L} =$  \quad \begin{tikzcd}[cramped] 1 
 \arrow[out=0,in=90,loop, "\alpha"]\end{tikzcd}entonces $S(1) = \quad <\{ 
 \alpha ^n : \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}> \quad = \quad k^{\mathbb{N}}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a smaller loop.  Also your math spacing and choice of delimiters is a brutal abomination, I fixed it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

La necesidad de que $Q$ no tenga ciclos dirigidos es para que los    
espacios vectoriales tengan dimensión finita en cada vértice. Por 
ejemplo, si $\mathbb{L} = \begin{tikzcd}[cramped] 1 
  \arrow[loop right, "\alpha"]\end{tikzcd}$ entonces $S(1) = \langle\{ 
\alpha ^n : \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}\rangle = k^{\mathbb{N}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also noticed another typo; it should be $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, not $\alpha$! thanks